# specify ssl key and ssl cert values instead of filename for MongoClient

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodes

I am currently creating a MongoClient in a node.js app as follows and the connection works fine. My issue is that I now want to pass the value of the key and the value of the cert as options into the MongoClient constructor instead of the file locations. Is this possible?

`mongoClient = new MongoClient(connStr, { sslKey: sslKeyPath, sslCert: sslCertPath, serverApi: ServerApiVersion['serverApiVer'] });`

Comment: What do you mean by "value of the cert"?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I want to pass in the certification content, not a file that holds the content.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. But you can save the content into a temporary file, it is used only once at connection time. How can you have the content as variable? Certificates are always stored as file or in a certificate store.

Comment: Thanks, the file is encrypted, so I would need to decrypt and then save to file and remove. That may be my only option.